# ContainerRequestFilter returns wrong content type for entity

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, cxf

I want to make a global check for every request. Therefore, I use a [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) (without [`@PreMatching`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html)) and throw a [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html) with a response containing an error entity, if the check is not passed.

My problem is, that the content type of the response is not matching the [`Accept`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) header of the request. But if I throw the same exception in my resource, the response contains the right content type.

**Code:**

My entity:

```java
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/test")
@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestEntity {

    public TestEntity() {
        this.key = "error";
    }

    @XmlElement
    private String key;
}
```

My filter:

```java
@Named
public class TestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private boolean globalError = true;

    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (globalError) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(422).entity(new TestEntity()).build());
        }
    } 
}
```

My resource:

```java
@Named
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public void find() {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(422).entity(new TestEntity()).build());
    }
}
```

My CXF configuration:

```xml
<jaxrs:server address="/rest/v1" id="test">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="testResource" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.JAXBElementProvider" />
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
        <ref bean="testFilter" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**Test:**

Request:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/test-webapp/services/rest/v1/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Response with `globalError=true`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:testEntity xmlns:ns2="http://www.mycompany.com/test">
      <key>error</key>
</ns2:testEntity>
```

Response with `globalError=false`:

```
{"key":"error"}
```

**Questions:**

Why is the response different? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@pedrofb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371459/pedrofb) good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329813/5277820) I found a easier work-around using [`ContainerRequestContext#getAcceptableMediaTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getAcceptableMediaTypes--):

> Get a list of media types that are acceptable for the response.
>
> **Returns:**
>   a read-only list of requested response media types sorted according to their q-value, with highest preference first.

My modified filter:

```
@Named
public class TestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private boolean globalError = true;

    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (globalError) {
            MediaType mediaType = requestContext.getAcceptableMediaTypes().size() > 0 ? requestContext.getAcceptableMediaTypes().get(0) : null;
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(422).type(mediaType).entity(new TestEntity()).build());
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems default response  builder of `ContainerRequestFilter` does not use accept header to override the response content type. Its needed to add the content type to the `Response`

```
throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(422).type("applicati‌​on/json").entity(new TestEntity()).build()
```

One option to get the desired behaviour is inspecting the header before set `.type` in exception response (use `requestContext.abortWith()` instead of raise an exception)

This is an example to set `application/json` if it is found in the header or return the default type

```
public class TestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private boolean globalError = true;

    private String typeFromHeaders(ContainerRequestContext requestContext){
        List<String> acceptHeaders = requestContext.getHeaders().get("Accept");
        if (acceptHeaders != null){         
            for (String acceptHeader: acceptHeaders){
                if (acceptHeader.indexOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)>=0){
                    return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
                }   
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (globalError) {
            requestContext.abortWith(
                    Response.status(422).type(typeFromHeaders(requestContext)).entity(new TestEntity()).build());
        }
    } 
}
```